# CMake compile project with multiple mains and shared functions

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake

Let's suppose I have two source files `A` and `B`. Each one has a main and a public function.

```
A                 B
|__ main()        |__ main()
|__ foo()         |__ bar()
```

I want `bar` method to use `foo` function. How can I compile this in a CMake project?

With this configuration, `B` obviusly doesn't know `A`'s `foo` function.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(My_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -O3")

add_executable(A A.cpp)
add_executable(B B.cpp)
```

This configuration has obviusly both definitions of `main`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(My_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -O3")

set(SOURCE_FILES A.cpp)
add_library(A_lib STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES})

add_executable(A A.cpp)
add_executable(B B.cpp)

target_link_libraries(B A_lib)
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want? I'd like not to combine both mains, or separate `foo` and `A main` in two different files. Maybe using C++ headers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Split `A` into two source files:

- One containing the `main` function, and which is used by the `A` executable target but not the library.
- One containing the `foo` function, which is used by the `A_lib` library target.

Then use the library for the `A` executable target too.

That's the "best" solution IMO.

You *can* use preprocessor macros to conditionally compile the `main` function in `A.cpp`. But it's not really something I recommend.